# why the culture is not getting set in my application with Thread.Current code?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, wpf-controls, embedded-resource

I have created a localization application in WPF.  I have bind the controls in the xaml like this.

`<Label Name="languageLabel" Content="{x:Static Resources:Resources.languageLabel}"  Style="{StaticResource CommonRepSecStyle}" />`

Everything works fine but still I am not sure the techniques I applied are good. I created a resource manager and assigned the string values to controls like this.

```
        Dim culture As CultureInfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(cultureName)
        Dim localResource As System.Resources.ResourceManager = New System.Resources.ResourceManager("LocalTest.Resources", System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())

        languageLabel.Content = localResource.GetString("languageLabel", culture)
       stateLabel.Content = localResource.GetString("stateLabel", culture)
        cityLabel.Content = localResource.GetString("cityLabel", culture)
       stateComboBox.Text = localResource.GetString("stateComboBox", culture)
        cityComboBox.Text = localResource.GetString("cityComboBox", culture)
        infoLabel.Content = localResource.GetString("infoLabel", culture)
        infoTextBox.Text = localResource.GetString("infoTextBox", culture)
        localResources.ReleaseAllResources()
```

It does not seems to work until I assigned the values to the controls? Is there any way to improve this? Thank you!

Edit : The complete code is here

```
    Imports System.IO
    Imports System.Windows.Controls
    Imports System.Globalization
    Imports System.Configuration
    Imports System.Threading
    Imports System.ComponentModel
    Imports System.Resources
    Imports System.Windows.Markup
    Imports System.Reflection
    Imports System.Uri
    Namespace LocalTest

Public Class MainWindow
    Private cultureName As String


    Public Sub New()

        '    '    ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        '    '    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

    End Sub
    Private Sub Window_Loaded(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Loaded


    End Sub
    Private Sub ButtonEnglish_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles ButtonEnglish.Click
        cultureName = "en-US"

        SetControlsCulture()
        'Dim ob As Object
        'ob = Application.Current.TryFindResource("Resources.en-US.resx")

        'Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")
        'Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture  = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")

    End Sub

    Private Sub ButtonFrench_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles ButtonFrench.Click
        cultureName = "fr-CA"
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New CultureInfo("fr-CA")

        SetControlsCulture()

    End Sub
    ' Dim s As String = r.GetString("LabelContent", culture)
    'Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture
    'Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture


    ''' <summary>
    ''' Select the Controls Culture
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>

    Private Sub SetControlsCulture()
        Select Case cultureName
            Case "fr-CA"
                UIControlsBinding()
            Case "en-US"
                UIControlsBinding()
        End Select
    End Sub
   Private Sub UIControlsBinding()
        Dim culture As CultureInfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(cultureName)
        Dim localResource As System.Resources.ResourceManager = New      System.Resources.ResourceManager("LocalTest.Resources", System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
     languageLabel.Content = localResource.GetString("languageLabel", culture)
     stateLabel.Content = localResource.GetString("stateLabel", culture)
     cityLabel.Content = localResource.GetString("cityLabel", culture)
     stateComboBox.Text = localResource.GetString("stateComboBox", culture)
     cityComboBox.Text = localResource.GetString("cityComboBox", culture)
    infoLabel.Content = localResource.GetString("infoLabel", culture)
    infoTextBox.Text = localResource.GetString("infoTextBox", culture)
    localResources.ReleaseAllResources() 
    End Sub
    End class
    End Namespace
```

Comment: and why would you do that in code and not in XAML??

Comment: I did it in the xaml. But it does not change the culture until I implement it in the code behind.

Comment: Check this idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10039102/is-there-any-way-to-use-staticresource-in-a-wpf-control-library-and-be-able-to-v  In a nutshell: define your own class type, add custom properties on it, make these custom properties dependent on current culture and bind to them. This way your code doesn't have to know resource keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add resources in WPF add a `Resource.resx` and a `Resource.NL-nl.resx` (or language of choice) file to the properties folder of you project. Add a resource with name `StateLabel` and a value in each resourcefile. *Don't forget to change the Access Modifier to Public*

Add xml namespace to your window/usercontrol: `xmlns:Resources="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2.Properties"` (where WpfApplication2 is your application name)

Add a label to your window/usercontrol `<Label Content="{x:Static Resources:Resources.StateLabel}"></Label>`

To change language call this from code to set the appropriate language (in this case Dutch):

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("nl-NL");
```

Comment: I have done this already.  It is in vb.net and I have create a new folder Resources which has the language resource file.

Comment: and have tried the way you told me, but it did not work for me.

Comment: Ok. But it doesn't work? Why do you need to set the labels from code? What's the problem?

Comment: I did. It does not show any error in it when i build the application.

Comment: In your code you don't change the ui culture in the current thread.

Comment: Thank you for your time Ralf.  I have included the complete code.