# Using Mahapps.Metro and Element Host

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

I've installed MahApps.Metro which is a UI toolkit that theme up a WPF application, the app works fine but when I launch it using an Element Host from a Form App the toolkit doesn't load and shows up basic buttons not the styled ones from the toolkit

Thanks in advance

Comment: `Thanks in advance` - you're welcome. Please come back to StackOverflow when you have any questions.

Comment: The question is pretty clear : how to get mahapps styling inside an ElementHost

Comment: Mohamed Hesham try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326621/wpf-control-not-displaying-in-elementhost-in-winforms-app